# Create Flowchart in LibreOffice using Python

Tags: python, libreoffice, flowchart

There plenty of examples on how to use Python to control the LibreOffice text document and spreadsheet but very little documentation on how to use the drawing program.  I am trying to figure out how to draw a flowchart or at least some shapes in LibreOffice using Python. I am using Windows 10 and the Python 3.3 that came with LibreOffice 5.

There is a very good example of how to use spreadsheet [LibreOffice Python example](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html)

In the example the following lines are common if you use the text document, spreadsheet, drawing or other documents.

```
import socket  
import uno
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver =     localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )
ctx = resolver.resolve( "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" )
smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)
model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
```

The following code was also in the example to modify the spreadsheet program and it works great. The code puts "Hello World" and a number in the spreadsheet.

```
cell1 = active_sheet.getCellRangeByName("C4")
cell1.String = "Hello world"
cell2 = active_sheet.getCellRangeByName("E6")
cell2.Value = cell2.Value + 1
```

For the drawing program is there some similar commands to get an active sheet and get a list of shapes that can be drawn?  I may be looking in the wrong place but haven't found any documentation for the drawing program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working Python example:

```
import uno

def create_shape(document, x, y, width, height, shapeType):
    shape = document.createInstance(shapeType)
    aPoint = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Point")
    aPoint.X, aPoint.Y = x, y
    aSize = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Size")
    aSize.Width, aSize.Height = width, height
    shape.setPosition(aPoint)
    shape.setSize(aSize)
    return shape

def insert_shape():
    document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    drawPage = document.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0)
    shape = create_shape(
        document, 0, 0, 10000, 5000, "com.sun.star.drawing.RectangleShape")
    drawPage.add(shape)
    shape.setString("My new RectangleShape");
    shape.setPropertyValue("CornerRadius", 1000)
    shape.setPropertyValue("Shadow", True)
    shape.setPropertyValue("ShadowXDistance", 250)
    shape.setPropertyValue("ShadowYDistance", 250)
    shape.setPropertyValue("FillColor", int("C0C0C0", 16))  # blue
    shape.setPropertyValue("LineColor", int("000000", 16))  # black
    shape.setPropertyValue("Name", "Rounded Gray Rectangle")

# Functions that can be called from Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro.
g_exportedScripts = insert_shape,
```

There is fairly complete reference documentation at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Drawings/Working_with_Drawing_Documents.  Look especially under the "Shapes" pages (note the navigation on the right-hand side of the page).  For one thing, there is a page that gives a list of Shape Types, as you requested.

Since Python-UNO documentation is somewhat limited, you'll need to get used to reading examples in Java or Basic and adapting the code to Python, as I have done above.