# LibreOffice problems drawing hash marks in shape using Python

Tags: python-3.x, libreoffice

I am trying to create a hash mark pattern inside a shape using LibreOffice 5 on Windows 10 using the Python 3.3 that came with LibreOffice. Two thirds of the code is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852645/create-flowchart-in-libreoffice-using-python) with additional questions about creating hash marks at the end of the code listing.

This is the Python code I tried.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

import socket
import uno

# get the uno component context from the PyUNO runtime
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()

# create the UnoUrlResolver
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )

# connect to the running office
ctx = resolver.resolve( "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" )
smgr = ctx.ServiceManager

# get the central desktop object
desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)
model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()

# Create the shape
def create_shape(document, x, y, width, height, shapeType):
    shape = model.createInstance(shapeType)
    aPoint = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Point")
    aPoint.X, aPoint.Y = x, y
    aSize = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.awt.Size")
    aSize.Width, aSize.Height = width, height
    shape.setPosition(aPoint)
    shape.setSize(aSize)
    return shape

def formatShape(shape):
    shape.setPropertyValue("FillColor", int("FFFFFF", 16))  # blue
    shape.setPropertyValue("LineColor", int("000000", 16))  # black

    aHatch = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.drawing.Hatch")
    #HatchStyle = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.drawing.HatchStyle")
    #aHatch.Style=HatchStyle.DOUBLE;
    aHatch.Color=0x00ff00
    aHatch.Distance=100
    aHatch.Angle=450

    shape.setPropertyValue("FillHatch", aHatch)
    shape.setPropertyValue("FillStyle", "FillStyle.DOUBLE")

shape = create_shape(model, 0, 0, 10000, 10000, "com.sun.star.drawing.RectangleShape")
formatShape(shape)

drawPage.add(shape)
```

This code should set a double crosshatch pattern inside a rectangle but no pattern shows ups inside the rectangle.

```
aHatch = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.drawing.Hatch")
#HatchStyle = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.drawing.HatchStyle")
#aHatch.Style=HatchStyle.DOUBLE;
aHatch.Color=0x00ff00
aHatch.Distance=100
aHatch.Angle=450

shape.setPropertyValue("FillHatch", aHatch)
shape.setPropertyValue("FillStyle", "FillStyle.DOUBLE")
```

The line to set the hatch style pattern:

```
uno.RuntimeException: pyuno.getClass:
```

Fails with the following error

```
com.sun.star.drawing.HatchStyleis a ENUM, expected EXCEPTION,
```

Here are some links to [Java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openoffice/trunk/test/testuno/source/fvt/uno/sd/shape/ShapeProperties.java) and [BASIC](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Structure_of_Drawings) examples I used for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HatchStyle = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.drawing.HatchStyle")

This fails because [HatchStyle](http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1drawing.html#a021284aa8478781ba1b958b81da7b608) is an [Enum](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python#Enum), not a [Struct](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python#Struct_Instance).  To use the HatchStyle enum, follow one of the three ways in the python example from the Enum link.

> shape.setPropertyValue("FillStyle", "FillStyle.DOUBLE")

It looks like you are confusing "FillStyle.HATCH" and "HatchStyle.DOUBLE" from the example.  This is what the code should be in Python:

```
from com.sun.star.drawing.FillStyle import HATCH
shape.setPropertyValue("FillStyle", HATCH)
```

This seems to be missing as well:

```
drawPage = model.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0)
```

Comment: I got horizontal blue hatch marks after adding these two lines:  from com.sun.star.drawing.FillStyle import HATCH
shape.setPropertyValue("FillStyle", HATCH)
Is there something I need to add or change here to modify the color, angle and style of the hatch? aHatch.Color=0x00ff00
aHatch.Distance=100
aHatch.Angle=450
shape.setPropertyValue("FillHatch", aHatch)

Comment: I tested the [Basic example](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Structure_of_Drawings#Hatches).  On Ubuntu (LO 5.0.5), the example worked as advertised, and the hatch settings could be changed in any way.  However on Windows (LO 5.1.0 and AOO 4.1.2), although setting the `FillStyle` worked, setting `FillHatch` had no effect.  You may want to consider [reporting a bug](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport).

Comment: I am developing on a Windows 10 machine and will give the Python code a try on a Linux machine before reporting a bug.  I will also test the BASIC code on both Linux and Windows machines.